# Prevent access to files in directory

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with my .htaccess file. I want prevent directly access to files in directory using url but allow to get files via HTML and PHP code.

My directory structure is /public/media

First, I created .htaccess file in media directory:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

but this isn't work. Next, I modifed this file in different ways for example

```
<Files ~ "^.*">
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

or

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?,mydomain [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mydomain.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg)$ - [F]
```

Unfortunately, none of these codes work.

Main .htaccess in root directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php


</IfModule>
```

Comment: there is no difference between someone typing a URL or the HTML having a reference to a URL its all just a GET request

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is using service like Amazon S3 and using Temporary url https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#temporary-urls